# Error when launching kobuki_slam

Tags: ros, kinect-v2

I am trying to use kinect v2 with turtlebot and am following [this](https://github.com/bus710/sulcata) tutorial. Everything works fine except when I enter the command

```
roslaunch kobuki_slam kobuki_slam.launch
```

This gives an error namely

```
[ERROR] [1509445234.825467518]: Error connecting to Hokuyo: Could not open serial Hokuyo: /dev/ttyACM0 @ 115200 could not open serial device.
```

Do you have any idea why I might be getting this error?

Thanks!